# Native Query Jpa Repository Not working without Column specification

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hey everyone i have a class with too many relation am using springboot when i want to retreive the data from @Query via Hql i got a result of array of array and when i use NativeQuery i Can't select 1 element it's always Select *

here's my class

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="\"DEV\"")
public class Dev {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="\"IdDev\"")
private int id ;
@Column(name="\"NomDev\"")
private String nomdev;
@Column(name="\"NomDLL\"")
private String dll ;
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="\"IdEtatDev\"")
private EtatDev etatdev ;
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="\"IdEcu\"")
private Ecu ecu ; 


@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="\"VEH_BY_DEV\""
        ,joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="\"IdDev\"")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="\"GRPMOD\"")})

private Set<Vehid> vehid = new HashSet<>();
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Maj maj ; 



public Set<Vehid> getVehid() {
    return vehid;
}
public void setVehid(Set<Vehid> vehid) {
    this.vehid = vehid;
}
public Ecu getEcu() {
    return ecu;
}
public void setEcu(Ecu ecu) {
    this.ecu = ecu;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNomdev() {
    return nomdev;
}
public void setNomdev(String nomdev) {
    this.nomdev = nomdev;
}
public String getDll() {
    return dll;
}
public void setDll(String dll) {
    this.dll = dll;
}
public EtatDev getEtatdev() {
    return etatdev;
}
public void setEtatdev(EtatDev etatdev) {
    this.etatdev = etatdev;
}

public Dev() {
    super();
}
public Dev(int id, String nomdev, String dll, EtatDev etatdev, Ecu ecu, Set<Vehid> vehid) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.nomdev = nomdev;
    this.dll = dll;
    this.etatdev = etatdev;
    this.ecu = ecu;
    this.vehid = vehid;
} 



}
```

and this my repository class

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;



@Transactional 
public interface DevRepository extends JpaRepository<Dev, Integer> {


@Query(value="SELECT \"IdDev\"  "\NomDev\" FROM \"DEV\"  ",nativeQuery=true)
    List<Dev> getDevwithEtat() ; 
}
```

When i execute this it saye ERROR SQL "NomDLL" column not found

it's like it's only allowed to select all or not , maybe the result List so it can't return one field so if anyone has an idea about changing the result type so it can get a result of 2 fields or three not all thought .. feel free to answer ( ps  the \" is to escape and when i add the "\NomDev\" i got an error of

ERROR SQL "IdEtatDev" not found  )

any help would be appreciated

Comment: change "\NomDev\" with this \"NomDev\" in your sql query

Comment: i don't thing that going to solve my problem cuz  it's not how write it it return value structure that am not respecting so i need to make a special result type or it's not going to work like i want it to

Comment: then your result type Object array change List<Dev> with this  List<Object[]>

Comment: okey it worked but there's a lil problem this isn't Json  :/

Comment: yes you need to convert ,look at the google gson library I make answer to conwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly change `List<Dev> getDevwithEtat();` with this `List<Object[]> getDevwithEtat();`

and after convert json your `devRepository.getDevwithEtat()` result like this

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (Object[] result : devRepository.getDevwithEtat())
  map.put((Integer)result[0], (String)result[1]);
```

convert to json with Google Gson

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(map);
```